# Getting a Azure AD refresh token and auth code using MSAL

Tags: azure, ember.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am working on an application with Ruby on Rails back-end and EmberJS Front-end.

I would like to achieve the following.

1. Log in user with MSAL with Ember FE
2. Get the auth_code and pass on to the back end
3. From the back end, fetch access token and refresh token.
4. Use it to send email using azure Graph API.

Basically I would like to perform step 1 of azure ad auth, i.e. fetching the auth_code, at the front end. And then perform step 2 at the back end. And then refresh the tokens at the back-end as needed.

I believe MSAL provides no good way to achieve this. When user consents (Step 1), it uses the `auth_code` by itself to fetch `access_token` and `refresh_token` (Step 2), and cashes it without exposing the values. It invokes `acquireTokenSilent` method to refresh the tokens when needed.

I can see that MSAL also has a `ssoSilent` method, which performs only step 1 of auth and returns auth code. I tried to use it in the following manner

```js
  signIn = () => {
    myMSALObj
      .loginPopup(loginRequest)
      .then(this.handleResponse)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  handleResponse = (resp) => {
    console.log('>>>> Response', resp);

    // this.token = resp;
    if (resp !== null) {
      username = resp.account.username;
      //  showWelcomeMessage(resp.account);
      resp.account = myMSALObj.getAccountByUsername(username);
      console.log('Resp => ', resp);
      myMSALObj
        .ssoSilent(resp)
        .then((r) => {
          console.log(r);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('Error ->', e);
        });
    } else {
      //  loadPage();
    }
  };
```

This always ends up in the following error

> InteractionRequiredAuthError: interaction_required: Silent authentication was denied. The user must first sign in and if needed grant the client application access to the scope ...

Even when the user has just consented for these scopes.

Is there something I am missing?

or

Is there any better way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance for any help

I am using Rails 6 with Ember 4.1

Comment: what's your ember / ember-source version?

Comment: and rails / azure / other relevant versions of libraries you may be using?

Comment: thanks! afaict, as long as your functions are being called, the ember-side of this is good -- though I find promise chains to be a bit antiquated compared to async/await.

Is your error from the rails side? or from whatever MSAL library you're using?

Do you have an open source reproduction available somewhere (I'm very rusty with rails)

Comment: The error is completely within the Ember side. Rails is probably irrelevant to this question. I described what I trying to do to give a holistic picture.

Comment: do you have a reproduction? I have a hunch the error is from one of your libraries or in the network.

The error you show does not reside anywhere within ember framework, but I'm more than happy to help you find out what is throwing it!

Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: This is a bit old but it might help figure out MSAL with Ember. https://github.com/visualjeff/ember-aad2-msal. The app has a service for authenticating with MSAL